# Calculating angle in isometric view

Tags: optimization, mathematics, computational-geometry, haxe

I have an angle where I need to convert a 'normal' angle to an isometric angle (116 degrees), and I came up with this function. It works, but I was wondering if the math could be optimized/simplified, or if this is the way to go. It's for a mobile game.

```
public static inline var ISO:Float = 0.45378560551; // (116-90) / 180 * PI=;

function convert(angle:Float):Float
{ 
  angle -= Math.PI; // corrected angle 

  var randomChoosenDistance = 2.0; // could be anything, I'm only interested in final angle.

  // calculate new line, using isometic angle.
  var x1 = Math.cos(angle - ISO);
  var x2 = Math.cos(angle - ISO) * randomChoosenDistance;
  var y1 = Math.sin(angle);
  var y2 = Math.sin(angle) * randomChoosenDistance;

  var dx = x1 - x2;
  var dy = y1 - y2;

  angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  return angle;
}
```

Can I get the new angle, without calculating the angle between the temporary points I'm creating at the moment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@neo pointed out that `dx` can be calculated as `(1 - r) * Math.cos(a - b)`.  Similarly, `dy = (1 - r) * Math.sin(a)`.  However, when you take `dy / dx`, which is what `Math.atan2(dy, dx)` implicitly does with its arguments, the `(1 - r)` factor cancels out.  You can also see, using a geometric argument, that (*x*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>) is pointless (pardon the pun).

[image: Pointlessness of (x2, y2)]

Therefore, `Math.atan2(y1, x1)` would work just the same as `Math.atan2(dy, dx)`.

---

So far, your function can be simplified to the following.  Since you repurposed `angle` twice, I need to disambiguate them as `alpha`, `beta`, and `theta` for this discussion.

```
public static inline var ISO:Float = 0.45378560551; // (116-90) / 180 * PI=;

function convert(alpha:Float):Float
{ 
  var beta = alpha - Math.PI; // corrected angle 

  // calculate new line, using isometic angle.
  var x1 = Math.cos(beta - ISO);
  var y1 = Math.sin(beta);

  var theta = Math.atan2(y1, x1);
  return theta;
}
```

---

But wait, there's more!  There's a mysterious correction from `alpha` to `beta`, and the cosine expression is complicated.

Let's start with `Math.sin(beta)`.  That's `Math.sin(-alpha)`, or `-Math.sin(alpha)`.

It would be nice to say `Math.atan2(Math.sin(alpha), something)` instead of `Math.atan2(-Math.sin(alpha), something)`.  Let's move the negation into the denominator then, for `var theta = Math.atan2(Math.sin(alpha), -x1)`.

Can we simplify `-x1`?

```
-x1 = -Math.cos(beta - ISO)
    = Math.cos(beta - ISO + 180°)
    = Math.cos(alpha - 180° - ISO + 180°)
    = Math.cos(alpha - ISO)
```

So, your function simplifies to:

```
public static inline var ISO:Float = 0.45378560551; // = (116-90) / 180 * PI

function convert(angle:Float):Float
{ 
    return Math.atan2(Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(angle - ISO));
}
```

Not only is the code more efficient, it's also less mysterious: the transformation is taking the x-coordinate of each point as if it were rotated 26° clockwise!

---

I have to question the motivation behind this function, though.  This isn't an angle-preserving transformation, so why are you operating on an angle?  Normally, you transform points' coordinates using matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to this in-depth answer! It's very clear. About how I'm using this function: I have spritesheets from an old game that are drawn in isometric perspective, but my game itself runs in normal perspective (it only _looks_ isometric). I'm using this function to get the right index on the spritesheet. So yes; I have to admit this function is very project specific.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that this is a math related question rather than code review. Let's simplified the code first,

```
var dx = Math.cos(a - b) - Math.cos(a - b) * r;
```

The above can be simplified to

```
var dx = (1 - r) * Math.cos(a - b);
```

One less Math.cos and one less multiplication is being called, which could be CPU consuming.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for simplified code, this helps a lot.